# Newly created contact randomly disappear on Android

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail

I have Sony Xperia Z3 compact running on Android 5.1.1 and experiencing problem with contacts.

When I'm creating a new contact by default it creates it on my google account (instead of phone memory).

After a few minutes this newly created contact might randomly disappear. It doesn't happen all the time, it's very random.

I think it has something to do with syncing, but not sure, please advice.

Comment: I have the same issue with Android 6. Doesn't seem to be random tho, but when you swipe-close the contacts application. Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: No, I just disabled auto-sync for contacts.